# IQueryable Extension: create lambda expression for querying a column for a keyword

Tags: c#, lambda, extension-methods

I started with the IQueryable extension methods from this example on [CodePlex](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/MVCFlexigrid.aspx).

What i believe i need is an IQueryable extension method to "Where", where the method signature looks like:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Where<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string columnName, string keyword)
```

and effectively does this (assuming T.columnName is of type string):

```
source.Where(p => p.ColumnName.Contains("keyword"))
```

using the above CodePlex example, i think i understand how he got the OrderBy method working, but my problem seems a bit more complex and I don't know how to get the Contains("keyword") part working.

Thanks in advance,

--Ed

Update: 9/13/2010 6:26pm PST

I thought the following would work, but end up getting a NotSupportedException (The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.) when I execute the expression via Count().  Any ideas?

```
    public static IQueryable<T> Where<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string columnName, string keyword)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var property = type.GetProperty(columnName);
        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
            var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
            var sel = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(propertyAccess, parameter);
            var compiledSel = sel.Compile();
            return source.Where(item => compiledSel(item).Contains(keyword));
        }
        else
        {
            return source;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you ever solve the "not supported in LINQ to Entities" problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
public static IQueryable<T> Where<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> source, string columnName, string keyword)
{
    var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");

    var body = Expression.Call(
        Expression.Property(arg, columnName),
        "Contains",
        null,
        Expression.Constant(keyword));

    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, arg);

    return source.Where(predicate);
}
```

Comment: this won't work because Queryable.Contains expects type T as a parameter, not string.  This is why I need to do Queryable.Where(p => p.EdsColumn.Contains("searchthis")

Comment: @Ed.S.: Changed `T` to `string`. Is that better?

Comment: I think there needs to be two bodies.  One for the String.Contains and another for the Where.

    var stringBody = Expression.Call(
        typeof(string),
        "Contains",
        new Type[] { typeof(string) },
        Expression.Property(arg, columnName),
        Expression.Constant(keyword));

    var whereBody = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        "Where",
        new Type[] { typeof(Queryable) },
        -- this is where i get lost.

Comment: @Ed.S.: Your `whereBody` is exactly what `return source.Where(predicate);` in my code returns. It first builds the predicate `p => p.ColumnName.Contains("keyword")` and then returns `source.Where(predicate)`.

Comment: @dtb: still getting "No method 'Contains' exists on type 'System.String'."  Any ideas?  In the body I changed both "typeof" to be of string since Queryable.Contains<T>(this IQueryable<T>,...) wouldn't work

Comment: @Ed.S.: Oh, you're talking about [String.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) and not [Queryable.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338641.aspx). I've changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: @dtb: thanks for the help - works like a charm.  I'm now going to try to get this to work for other column data types.

Comment: @dtb Should this work with linq2entities?  In most places this works, because it is actually doing linq2objects(verified via profiler).  If I put this in a query where it is forced to run with linq2entities, I get "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method...this method cannot be translated into a store expression."  I have been struggling with this for a couple days.

Answer (score 7):

Well a couple of years later, but if anybody still need this, here it is:

```
    public static IQueryable<T> Has<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, string keyword)
    {
        if (source == null || propertyName.IsNull() || keyword.IsNull())
        {
            return source;
        }
        keyword = keyword.ToLower();

        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType, String.Empty);
        var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);

        var CONTAINS_METHOD = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
        var TO_LOWER_METHOD = typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", new Type[] { });

        var toLowerExpression = Expression.Call(property, TO_LOWER_METHOD);
        var termConstant = Expression.Constant(keyword, typeof(string));
        var containsExpression = Expression.Call(toLowerExpression, CONTAINS_METHOD, termConstant);

        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(containsExpression, parameter);

        var methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Where",
                                    new Type[] { source.ElementType },
                                    source.Expression, Expression.Quote(predicate));

        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(methodCallExpression);
    }
```

I called my method "Has" just to keep it short, sample usage:

```
filtered = filtered.AsQueryable().Has("City", strCity)
```

And you can concatenate to make it even more expressive:

```
filtered = filtered.AsQueryable().Has("Name", strName).Has("City", strCity).Has("State", strState);
```

By the way, the "IsNull()" attached to the strings is just another simple extension method:

```
    public static Boolean IsNull(this string str)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(str);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.Contains("keyword")` part is exactly right in your example.

It's the `p.ColumnName` part that's going to cause trouble.

Now, there are a number of ways of doing this, generally involving either reflection or `Expression<>`, neither of which is particularly efficent.

The problem here is by passing the column name as a string, you are doing to undo that exact thing LINQ was invented to allow.

However, there are probably better ways of accomplishing your overall task besides that way.

So, let's look at alternate ways:

You want to be able to say :

```
   var selector = new Selector("Column1", "keyword");
   mylist.Where(item => selector(item));
```

and have it was the equivalent of

```
    mylist.Where(item=> item.Column1.Contains("keyword"));
```

How 'bout we go with:

```
   Func<MyClass, string> selector = i => i.Column1;
   mylist.Where(item => selector(item).Contains("keyword"));
```

or

```
   Func<MyClass, bool> selector = i => i.Column1.Contains("keyword");
   mylist.Where(item => selector(item));
```

These are easily expanded for alternatives:

```
   Func<MyClass, string> selector;
   if (option == 1)
        selector = i => i.Column1;
   else
        selector = i => i.Column2;
   mylist.Where(item => selector(item).Contains("keyword"));
```

Comment: Thanks, i've incorporated your suggestions into my "work in progress".

Answer (score 0):

See, in generics type of the object works dynamically. So when p.ColumnName is taken as string, the Contains of string is been executed.

Generally for any lambda expression you specify, it parses the thing into an Expression and ultimately produces the output at runtime.

If you see my post :
http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/09/use-of-expression-trees-in-lamda-c.html
you will understand how it works actually.