# Add Linq where condition to generic IQueryable<T>

Tags: .net, linq, generics

Basicaly what I'd like to do is :

```
var validValues = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 34 };

query = query.Where(item => validValues.Contains(item.Value));
```

Except that I don't know what type it is, I'd like to do it as an extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Where<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, IList<int> accpetedValues)
{
   if (accpetedValues == null || !accpetedValues.Any() || string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
      return source;

   // HERE

   return source;
}
```

I've found this post [IQueryable Extension: create lambda expression for querying a column for a keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703386/iqueryable-extension-create-lambda-expression-for-querying-a-column-for-a-keywo)
but it's not what I want and I can't figure out how to adapt it to my case...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to filter out valid values? Because you're `Where` extension returning items.

Comment: Trying to add a where condition to a the IQueryable

Comment: I want to keep the data where a certain property value is included in the valid values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a better version of where with dynamic expression with Generic valid values collection:

```
    public static IQueryable<Tsource> Where<Tsource, Tproperty>(this IQueryable<Tsource> source, Expression<Func<Tsource, Tproperty>> property, IList<int> accpetedValues)
    {
        var propertyName = ((MemberExpression)property.Body).Member.Name;

        if (accpetedValues == null || !accpetedValues.Any() || string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
            return source;

        var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Tsource), "item");
        var selector = Expression.PropertyOrField(item, propertyName);
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Tsource, bool>>(
            Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Contains", new[] { typeof(Tproperty) },
                Expression.Constant(accpetedValues), selector),
            item);
        return source.Where(predicate);
    }
```

**Usage:**

```
query = query.Where(item => item.Value, validValues));
```

Comment: This is working good except that if my property is of type int? and my accepted values list is of type List<int>, I get an error, I will check how to fix it

Answer (score 2):

It's similar to the linked post, but this time you need to dynamically build [`Expression<Func<T, bool>>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710(v=vs.110).aspx) using [`Expression.Call`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.call(v=vs.110).aspx) to call [`Enumerable.Contains<int>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.100).aspx) like this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Where<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, IList<int> accpetedValues)
{
    if (accpetedValues == null || !accpetedValues.Any() || string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
        return source;

    var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
    var selector = Expression.PropertyOrField(item, propertyName);
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Contains", new[] { typeof(int) },
            Expression.Constant(accpetedValues), selector),
        item);
    return source.Where(predicate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make it to work with arbitrary collections (not just IList) - you can do it like this:

```
static class Extensions {
    public static IQueryable<TEntity> WhereContains<TEntity, TProperty>(this IQueryable<TEntity> source, IList<TProperty> accpetedValues, Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> property) {
        if (accpetedValues == null || !accpetedValues.Any())
            return source;

        var member = property.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (member == null)
            return source; // better throw

        string propertyName = member.Member.Name;
        var containsMethod = typeof (ICollection<TProperty>).GetMethod("Contains"); // get Contains method of IList
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof (TEntity), "p");
        var memberAccess = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName); // p.ValidValue (for example)
        var list = Expression.Constant(accpetedValues); // your list
        var body = Expression.Call(list, containsMethod, memberAccess); // list.Contains(p.ValidValue)
        return source.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(body, parameter));
    }
}
```

Note I also use property access expression instead of passing property name as string - this is more type-safe. Use like this:

```
var validValues = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 34 };
query = query.WhereContains(validValues, item => item.ValidValue);
```