# C# Using dynamic Linq expressions filter a column that is of type int using Startswith and getting Nullable`1 for conversion

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

As a basis for filtering using dynamic linq I used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9831761/5750758) and it works for columns of type String however I also needed to do startsWith/Contains on integer type columns as well - in this case I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19318810/5750758) - and it falls over with the error shown a little below.

Here is the code that creates the IQueryable result.

```
    public static IQueryable<T> Has<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, ExpressionFilter filter) {
    if (source == null || filter.PropertyName.IsNull() || filter.Value == null) {
        return source;
    }
    // Find the type incase we get an int column.
    Type propertyType = source.ElementType.GetProperty(filter.PropertyName).PropertyType;

    // For our Call.
    MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression = null;

    // If its a string we need to change it to lower case.
    MethodCallExpression toLowerExpression = null;

    // If its any one of the binary expressions.
    Expression binaryExpression = null;

    // ..and our predicate is initiated here as well.
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null;

    // We need the parameter eg x => ..
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType, "x");

    // Finally here is our Property expression eg x => LastName Last name being the property name
    Expression propertyExp = Expression.Property(parameter, filter.PropertyName);

    // our METHODINFO's
    var CONTAINS_METHOD = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
    var STARTS_WITH_METHOD = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new[] { typeof(string) });
    var ENDS_WITH_METHOD = typeof(string).GetMethod("EndsWith", new[] { typeof(string) });
    var BOOL_EQUAL_METHOD = typeof(bool).GetMethod("Equals", new Type[] { typeof(bool) });
    var TO_LOWER_METHOD = typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", new Type[] { });
    var TRIM_START = typeof(string).GetMethod("Trim", new Type[] { typeof(int) });
    var STRING_CONVERT = typeof(SqlFunctions).GetMethod("StringConvert", new[] { typeof(double?) }); ////get the SqlFunctions.StringConvert method for nullable double

    // We supply a type of object for our term to search on.. it needs to be a string.
    ConstantExpression termConstant = Expression.Constant(filter.Value.ToString(), typeof(string));

    // In case we get a propertyType of (int) we cant just perform a lower case on it.
    if (propertyType == typeof(string)) {
        toLowerExpression = Expression.Call(propertyExp, TO_LOWER_METHOD);
    }

    switch (filter.Comparison) {
        case Comparison.Contains:
            methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(toLowerExpression, CONTAINS_METHOD, termConstant);
            break;
        case Comparison.StartsWith:
            if (propertyType == typeof(int)) { // We'll do a startsWith on an int column

                //convert Expression to a nullable double (or nullable decimal),
                //so that you can use SqlFunctions.StringConvert
                propertyExp = Expression.Convert(propertyExp, typeof(double?));

                //call StringConvert on your converted expression
                propertyExp = Expression.Call(null, STRING_CONVERT, propertyExp);

                methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(propertyExp, STARTS_WITH_METHOD, termConstant);
            }
            else
                methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(toLowerExpression, STARTS_WITH_METHOD, termConstant); //WORKS HERE..

            break;
        case Comparison.EndsWith:
            methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(toLowerExpression, ENDS_WITH_METHOD, termConstant);
            break;
        case Comparison.BoolTest:
            bool parsedBoolValue;

            if (bool.TryParse(filter.Value.ToString().ToLower(), out parsedBoolValue)) { // Its a bool column.
                termConstant = Expression.Constant(parsedBoolValue, typeof(bool));
                methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(propertyExp, BOOL_EQUAL_METHOD, termConstant);
            }
            break;
        case Comparison.Equal:
            binaryExpression = Expression.Equal(propertyExp, termConstant);
            break;
        case Comparison.GreaterThan:
            binaryExpression = Expression.GreaterThan(propertyExp, termConstant);
            break;
        case Comparison.GreaterThanOrEqual:
            binaryExpression = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(propertyExp, termConstant);
            break;
        case Comparison.LessThan:
            binaryExpression = Expression.LessThan(propertyExp, termConstant);
            break;
        case Comparison.LessThanOrEqual:
            binaryExpression = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(propertyExp, termConstant);
            break;
        case Comparison.NotEqual:
            binaryExpression = Expression.NotEqual(propertyExp, termConstant);
            break;
        case Comparison.IndexOf:
            binaryExpression = Expression.NotEqual(
                Expression.Call(
                    propertyExp,
                    "IndexOf",
                    null,
                    Expression.Constant(filter.Value, typeof(string)),
                    Expression.Constant(StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, typeof(StringComparison))
                ),
                Expression.Constant(-1, typeof(int))
            );
            break;
        default:
            return null;
    }

    if (binaryExpression == null) {
        predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(methodCallExpression, parameter);
    }
    else {
        predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(binaryExpression, parameter);
    }

    methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Where",
                                        new Type[] { source.ElementType },
                                        source.Expression, Expression.Quote(predicate));

    return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(methodCallExpression);
}
```

So it works with columns of string type but when you try and do a filter on an int column it fails with..

> "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."

For an int column it builds the expression with:

```
            if (propertyType == typeof(int)) { // We'll do a startsWith on an int column

                //convert Expression to a nullable double (or nullable decimal),
                //so that you can use SqlFunctions.StringConvert
                propertyExp = Expression.Convert(propertyExp, typeof(double?));

                //call StringConvert on your converted expression
                propertyExp = Expression.Call(null, STRING_CONVERT, propertyExp);

                methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(propertyExp, STARTS_WITH_METHOD, termConstant);
            }
```

and as an expression this yields

> {x => StringConvert(Convert(x.ClientNo,
>   Nullable`1)).StartsWith("101")}

[image]

I could be wrong here but why would it put a back tick and a "1" after nullable?? is this why it falls over?

For completeness at the point it completes the "Has" method (adds to the expression tree) and this is the result (which fails):
[image]

Is there a better way to construct this expression so it works?

Comment: What is used as datasource? List, Array or other in-memory collection? EntityFramework?

Comment: Sorry.. its entity framework..

Comment: EF6 or EF Core? Version? From exception message I have a feeling you are using some preview version of EF Core 3.0. Most of the 3.0 previews have issues translating some expressions. And `SqlFunctions` are EF6 specific and are not supported in EF Core (in EF Core you should use  `.ToString()` instead).

Comment: ClientNo has type int? I see you call Convert(double), but pass there int. Can it be the reason?

Comment: Back tick and 1 just means it is a generic type with one parameter, i.e. Nullable<T>

Comment: Ivan I think you are on the money there.. I am using dotnet core... EF core... Preview 3.0.  I do believe it is to do with the convert and I am wondering how can I use .ToString instead..  ClientNo is typeof int32...

Comment: I wonder if someone might have a solution for this.. from what I gather its trying to convert a column from double? to string but its an int32 type... How can I do a conversion from int32 to string?